# Connect to WiFi in specific time

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi

How can I connect to my WiFi in a specific time. For example I want my notebook connect to a WiFi at 3:00 AM and disconnect at 7:00 AM. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Windows Scheduled Tasks to run a bat file that connects. 
You would need to make sure that your battery / power settings allowed the computer to be awake at that time or always on.

In the bat file I would use a command similar to this:

netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME